# JWT Authentication with React/Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, jwt

I am facing a 'strange' behavior while trying to implement an authentication using JWT httpOnly in a Node/React application.

Basically I have a "Login" service that would provide a response containing a httpOnly access token if the user and password are correct. If so, the response will be as follows:

(NODEjs - Login snippet)

```
res.cookie(
  "access_token",
  { token: token },
  {
    maxAge: 3600,
    httpOnly: true
  }
)
```

That means that from now on I can only call my APIs by using this web token in this case using parameter **withCredentials = true**

(Frontend Snippet)

```
handleTokenVerification(event){   
  axios.post('/auth/getUserInfo', {withCredentials: true})
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
  }).catch(err =>{
      console.log('ERRO: ' + err)
  })
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

It does work when a call a API for the first time, after that, it seems that this cookie was reset some how because de API does not work anymore.

Comment: There's probably not enough here to know what's going on but: do you know how to inspect your browser's debug tools in order to see what cookies are being sent? i.e., can you verify your hypothesis that the cookie is being reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the maxAge: 3600 parameter. Was too low and I was not able to perform a couple requests before it expired.